# Data unable to insert showing foreign key constraint fails error 1452

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

this is my table i try to insert data but its prevent to insert data in the database 
this is my insert query when run this query showing me Error like that

#1452 - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails 
(`godspeed`.`dev_phase_type`, CONSTRAINT `dev_phase_type_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY 
(`phase_id`) REFERENCES `dev_phase` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE)

this is my insert query when use this query data is not inserting database
INSERT INTO `dev_phase_type`(`abr`, `type`) VALUES (' 111eeee',' ee')

```
--
-- Table structure for table `dev_phase_type`
--

CREATE TABLE `dev_phase_type` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `phase_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `abr` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `type` varchar(250) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Dumping data for table `dev_phase_type`
--

INSERT INTO `dev_phase_type` (`id`, `phase_id`, `abr`, `type`) VALUES
(7, 1, 'F-P', 'Periodized'),
(8, 1, 'F-A', 'Ascending'),
(9, 2, 'G-P', 'Periodized'),
(10, 2, 'G-A', 'Ascending');

--
-- Indexes for dumped tables
--

--
-- Indexes for table `dev_phase_type`
--
ALTER TABLE `dev_phase_type`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  ADD KEY `phase_id` (`phase_id`);

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for dumped tables
--

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for table `dev_phase_type`
--
ALTER TABLE `dev_phase_type`
  MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=21;

--
-- Constraints for dumped tables
--

--
-- Constraints for table `dev_phase_type`
--
ALTER TABLE `dev_phase_type`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `dev_phase_type_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`phase_id`) REFERENCES `dev_phase` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;
COMMIT;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The foreign key cannot be defined since there's already data in the tables that do not conform with it.

Specifically you have the values `1` and `2` in the column `phase_id` in table `dev_phase_type`. Do those values exist already in the referenced table `dev_phase`?

I guess not. Check them, and make sure they makes sense before adding the foreign key.